# php check if date entered is weekend

Tags: php

I have a jquery ui datepicker with the weekends blocked off so people can't click them. I know you should never trust the users input and as the box can still be typed in they can still enter weekends. I tried this in php

```
if(date('w', strtotime($date)) == 6 || 'w', strtotime($date)) == 0)))) {
echo 'Event is on a weekday'; 
} else {
echo 'Event on a weekend';
}
```

Essentially, the or ||'s aren't actually being accessed for sundays (0) and it's only actually using saturday as the date.

can someone help?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
if(date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Sunday' || date('l', strtotime($date)) == 'Saturday'))))  {
    echo 'Event on a weekend';
} else {
    echo 'Event is on a weekday'; 
}
```

Or even you can try like

```
if(date('w', strtotime($date)) == 6 || date('w', strtotime($date)) == 0) {
    echo 'Event on a weekend';
} else {
    echo 'Event is on a weekday'; 
}
```

Comment: Be careful with comparing to strings _Sunday_ and _Saturday_ - if the locale is not English, this will fail.

Comment: @AleksG please see my second also

Comment: I used the second one, but as was my orginal problem, it detects weekdays as weekends and weekends as weekdays which is why i had to replace the text.

Comment: Essentially replace weekday with weekend and weekend with weekday and it works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With [DateTime::Format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) we can do as

```
$date = '2014-04-06' ; // Y-m-d 

$date = new DateTime($date);
$day =  $date->format("w");
if($day == 6 || $day == 0){
    echo 'Event on a weekend';
}else{
    echo 'Event on a weekday';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your `if` statement in addition to getting the logic the wrong way around.  It should be:

```
if(date('w', strtotime($date)) == 6 || date('w', strtotime($date)) == 0) {
    echo 'Event is on a weekend'; 
} else {
    echo 'Event on a weekday';
}
```

Comment: Thanks works on old PHP versions.